# How to Display Badges with Menu Items that are displayed in the overflow menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

I am Working on [Android Menu Items](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html). I can able to add Badges with the Items that are displayed in the [Action Bar](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-ActionItemBadge) .But i want to show the same Badges with the Overflow Menu Items. Is there any solutions to Add Badges to Menu Items in overflow menu Like the Sample Image  [image: Image 1] and [image: Image 2]

Any help would greatly appreciated..!!!

Comment: default menu item won't work for you, try popup window or popup menu for more customization

Comment: Show 'PopupWindow' with your custom layout when clicked on menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i did it with the Help ofCustom [PopUp Window](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) + [BadgeView](https://github.com/stefanjauker/BadgeView/blob/master/BadgeView/src/com/jauker/widget/BadgeView.java)

Here what i have Done.

1. **Created Custom Layout For PopUp Window - custom_popup.xml**

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/icon"
           android:layout_width="36dp"
           android:layout_height="36dp"
           android:background="@drawable/icon_menu_facebook"
           android:text="Icon" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Notifications" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/badge"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView

           android:layout_width="36dp"
           android:layout_height="36dp"
           android:background="@drawable/icon_menu_facebook"
           android:text="Icon" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Notifications" />

       <TextView

           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView

           android:layout_width="36dp"
           android:layout_height="36dp"
           android:background="@drawable/icon_menu_facebook"
           android:text="Icon" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Notifications" />

       <TextView

           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

2.**Added Menu Item with Custom Icon (Overflow Menu Icon)- options_menu.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ViewSource"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_viewsource"
        android:title="ViewSource"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
        android:title="About"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
        <!-- "file" submenu -->
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/github"
                android:icon="@drawable/icon_menu_github"
                android:title="Github" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/linkedin"
                android:icon="@drawable/icon_menu_linkedin"
                android:title="LinkedIn" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/twitter"
                android:icon="@drawable/icon_menu_twitter"
                android:title="Twitter" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:icon="@drawable/icon_menu_facebook"
                android:title="Facebook" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        android:title="More"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>

</menu>
```

3. **In MainActivity.java Added the following Code with in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)**

   ```
         case R.id.notifications:
               LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               View CustomPopUp = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_popup, null);
               popupWindow = new PopupWindow(CustomPopUp, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                       ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                   popupWindow.setElevation(5.0f);
               }
               ViewGroup actionBar = getActionBar(getWindow().getDecorView());
               TextView tv_badge = (TextView) CustomPopUp.findViewById(R.id.badge);
               BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(activity);
               badge.setTargetView(tv_badge);
               badge.setBadgeCount(45);
               popupWindow.showAtLocation(actionBar, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT, 0, -70);
               popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);
               linearlatout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       popupWindow.dismiss();
                   }
               });
               return true;
          default:
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   ```

Thats all..!!! Happy Coding...!!!

Answer (score 2):

can you please try following.

```
main.xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/badge_layout"
        android:title="Badges"
        android:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Here `badge_layout` is you menu item layout with the badge.

and following are code to implement in activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();
        mCounter = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This is for android:showAsAction="always" But I  need a solution for android:showAsAction="never"